# How to select value from kendo ComboBox using selenium webdriver C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

How to Get the Value from the Kendo ComboBox by using Selenium web driver?

```
  <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input ng-scope" unselectable="on">Select Company </span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
</span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-Medical-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
</span>
<select class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="BigCompany" style="width: 100%; display:none ;" kendo-drop-down-list="" required="" k-option-label="{id: '', value: 'Select Company Type...'}" k-data-source="BigCompany" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-data-text-field="'value'" ng-model="data.companyTypeId" ng-disabled="isCompanyProfile" data-role="dropdownlist">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Company Type...</option>
<option value="1">prise</option>
</select>
```

I made the effort with JavaScript but fail to save as it by pass the value and field remains mandatory.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript(string.Format("$('[name ={0}]').data('kendoDropDownList').value('{1}')", "BigCompany", "1"));
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `WebDriver` instead of JSE? It should work. It looks like you are actually sending JQuery and not JS. Are you able to execute that command successfully in the dev toolbar on the page?

Comment: @JeffC: Yes I tried with webdriver as well but it fail and I am able to execute the command successfully in dev toolbar.